# how to import puppeteer npm in nodejs

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');

async function grabStocks(url){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newpage();
    await page.goto(url);


    const[el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="home-contents"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]')
    const src = await el.getProperty('src');
    const srcTxt = await src.jasonValue();

    console.log({srcTxt});
}



grabStocks ('http://www.nepalstock.com/todaysprice');
```

The error is this

```
> [roshan@fedora Web scraping project]$ node nepalstock.js
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888   throw err;   ^
> 
> Error: Cannot find module '/home/roshan/Web scraping
> project/nepalstock.js'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
>     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: []
```

I had installed the puppeteer in the same folder but it is showing this error.

Comment: @Ajay2707: read the actual error

Comment: It seems that ```nepalstock.js``` doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a problem that you haven't exported your `grabstocks()` method.
Maybe `module.exports = {grabstocks}` inside this file should do the trick :)

```
  const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');
    async function grabStocks(url){
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newpage();
        await page.goto(url);
    
    
        const[el] = await page.$x('//*[@id="home-contents"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]')
        const src = await el.getProperty('src');
        const srcTxt = await src.jasonValue();
    
        console.log({srcTxt});
    }

module.exports = {grabstocks}
```

and then can try to use it.
But again as the error says `nepalstock.js module not found` maybe cuz you haven't exported any method of it that you wanna use . Just guessing :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't init npm correctly.

`npm init -y`